# how can we block calls, sms and notifications?

Tags: android

i want to block call/sms and notification in android studio so anyone can help me through **source code**.
is android os gives permission to block call/sms and notification?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the SMS is now only possible if you are chosen by the user to be it's main SMS app, so if you want your app to just block some messages and use your normal messaging app for the rest, it won't be possible.

For the help doing it, here's a great tutorial : [android authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-create-an-sms-app-721438/amp/)